# How can I create a toggle button similar to the Twitter apps location toggle button?

Tags: android, togglebutton

What custom button should I use which could be slided right and left such as on turn on/off location button on android's twitter app as the picture below:

[image]

[image]

and also any link or guide to create such button ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) in combination with a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) set as its background.

A sample of the `ToggleButton` is to be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#ToggleButton).

Basically you create an image for the checked and unchecked state of the button. You set the appropriate images in the `StateListDrawable` and set that `StateListDrawable` as the `ToggleButtos`'s background.

Comment: Thank you, I have successfully made custom toggle button using StateListDrawable.