# Android Toggle Button / Segmented Button

Tags: android, togglebutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a toggle button similar to the Twitter apps location toggle button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978689/how-can-i-create-a-toggle-button-similar-to-the-twitter-apps-location-toggle-but)

I am looking to create a Toggle Button Like in the  Screen below.

[image]

Where when you click One way that thats highlighted and when someone clicks round Trip that gets highlighted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978689/how-can-i-create-a-toggle-button-similar-to-the-twitter-apps-location-toggle-but

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a segmented control not toggle button...

http://ttlnews.blogspot.in/2011/09/segmented-button-control-in-android.html

http://www.4shared.com/get/jEyGPPPo/FoursquaredSegmentedButton.html

Comment: Thanks Samir :) damn coming from CSS/ jQuery u tend to forget Android is not the same :P

Comment: see 4shared link in my answer is exact what you want

Comment: yeah i have imported that into my project.. but getting stylable errors ..

Comment: check styles file in res->values->styles.xml

Comment: damn thats 400 lines of code :P wondering which ones to pick

Comment: yup i know that but delete carefully, some field are necessary...

Comment: yeah removing it style by style so that later i can import it into the my project. is it ok if create a different package and import it ?

Comment: am getting the following error http://pastebin.com/SJStNSqG

Comment: you have to change all parameter in main as your packages name ...

Comment: i have changed it into import com.ksrtc.widget.SegmentedButton;
import com.ksrtc.widget.SegmentedButton.OnClickListenerSegmentedButton;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7795/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-samir)

Answer (score 2):

One way is having a view group with two buttons. Initially Both buttons are clickable.
when Button1 is clicked you can disable it and enable Button2 and vice versa.

There will be drawable states for enabled/disable button. This gives feeling of segmented control  widget.

Answer (score 1):

What about using 2 different graphics for the button?
One with a highlighted left and one with a highlighted right side?

So basically it's just one button having two graphics...